# Help with finding time constant from graph

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, linear-control

Given the following for oven temperature decay,

[image]

I have to find the time constant and temperature outside the oven. The answers given in the book are:

$\tau=35.8 \text{ sec}$,  Outside Temp = $40^{\circ}C$.

The instructor stated that these values are incorrect and wants us to find the correct solution.  I got the following values for $\tau$ but not sure if I am approaching this problem correctly:

$\dfrac{d\theta}{dt} \big|_{t=0}=\dfrac{1}{\tau}=\dfrac{12^{\circ}C}{470\text{ sec}}$

$\tau=39.175 \text{ sec}$

This is close to what the book has, but I feel it might be wrong based on the total time it takes for the system to reach its final value (~4250 sec).  I also tried normalizing by the total $\Delta T$ and I get $\tau = 3,113.75 \text{ sec}$, which just seems way too high.

What is the best method of approaching such a problem?

Comment: Assuming the model is Newton's law of cooling, you really have three parameters: the final temperature (i.e. the "outside temperature"), the difference between the initial and final temperatures, and the time constant. Given any three of the given points, you can find unique values of the parameters that make the curve go through those three points. But the other points may or may not lie on that curve. If they don't, then you want to do some kind of "overfitting" such as least squares to find the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that the low of cooling is :
$$\theta(t)=\theta_{out}+\beta\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\tau}\right)$$
$t$ is the time, $\theta$ is the temperature, $\theta_{out}$ is the outside temperature, $\tau$ is the time constant and $\beta$ is a coefficient.

$$\ln\left(\theta(t)-\theta_{out}\right)=\ln(\beta)-\frac{t}{\tau}$$
Thus, the graphical representation of $\quad\ln\left(\theta(t)-\theta_{out}\right)\quad$ vs. $t$ should be $\underline{\text{linear}}$.

This is drawn in BLACK on the figure below in case of $\theta_{out}=40.\quad$ Obviously, the curve is far from a straight line. This confirmes that $\theta_{out}=40$ is false.

[image]

The drawings for various values of $\theta_{out}$ show that the best linear fit is obtained with $\theta_{out}\simeq 0.$

The case $\theta_{out}\simeq 0$ is drawn in red. In order to compare, the straight line is drawn in black dots.

The approximate values of $\beta$ and $\tau$ can be computed thanks to linear regression ($\theta_{out}= 0)$ according to the equation :
$$\ln\left(\theta(t)\right)=\ln(\beta)-\frac{t}{\tau}$$
Which leads to : $\beta\simeq 120$ and $\tau\simeq 3900$.

This is the best fit with criteria of least mean square $\underline{\text{relative}}$ deviation (because linear regression vs. the log function).

The result would be slightly different if the criteria was the least mean square deviation. This requires a non-linear method of calculus. But, in practice, the least relative deviation is often preferred.

Answer (score 0):

*In the same spirit as JJacquelin's answer.*

Consider that $\theta_{out}$ is fixed. Then, le linear regression gives $\beta$ and $\tau$ which are implict functions of  $\theta_{out}$. Recompute the values of the $\theta$'s and let $SSQ$ be the sum of the squares of the residuals.

Using the same values as JJacquelin for his plots, you would get the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\theta_{out} & SSQ \\
 -40 & 24.492 \\
 -30 & 18.867 \\
 -20 & 13.258 \\
 -10 & 8.173 \\
 0 & 4.647 \\
 10 & 4.843 \\
 20 & 13.330 \\
 30 & 39.862 \\
 40 & 104.916
\end{array}
\right)$$ Use the four values corresponding to $\theta_{out}=-10,0,10,20$ and compute the cubic going through the points. You should get
$$SSQ=0.000761715\, \theta_{out}^3+0.0186079\, \theta_{out}^2-0.242684 \,\theta_{out}+4.6471 \tag 1$$ Compute the derivative
$$\frac{d SSQ}{d \theta_{out}}= 0.00228515 \, \theta_{out}^2+0.0372157 \, \theta_{out}-0.242684$$ Set it equal to zero since you look for the minimum. This will give you two solutions $\theta_{out}\approx -21.3$ (to be discarded since outside the range) and $\theta_{out}\approx 5.0$.

For $\theta_{out}=5$, using $(1)$ you predict $SSQ=3.994$.

Repeat the linear regression using $\theta_{out}=5$ and you will get $SSQ=4.073$ (quite close, isn't it ?) and the required parameters.

A full nonlinear regression would have given $\theta_{out}=4.967$ and  $SSQ=4.073$ and the best parameters would have been $\beta=116.60$ and $\tau=3608$ almost the same as those given by JJacquelin.